# Goal: Remove filler ----'s after fold title || Issue: set fillchars="" does not work in NeoVim

Tags: vim, neovim

Here is my entire init.vim file (currently just trying to make it work - I will remove unnecessary code once the main objectives are in working order).

### The problem I am facing:

I cannot get rid of the trailing -'s once I have folded my code sections. The xtermbg of Fold is working as it normally would in a .vimrc file, but once it's put into this sysinit.vim (which is supposedly the same thing but for NeoVim, if I understand correctly), it doesn't want to work. I've checked the NeoVim change logs to no avail.

### What could be the problem?

The only difference that may be abnormal is that I have installed NeoVim through Choco on Windows 10. Therefore, it's entire installation is located in C:/tools/neovim/Neovim/. However, I cannot see how that may be an issue when all the other parts of it work.

Latest version of NeoVim, uninstalled and cleaned all old directories of Vim before installation.

```
" README
" Far from perfect. Definitely not optimized. Use at your own risk.


" Autocmd Commands
autocmd BufWinLeave *.* mkview
autocmd BufWinEnter *.* silent loadview


" Keybinds
nnoremap ; :


" Tab and Indent Settings
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set shiftround
set expandtab
set autoindent
set smartindent
set foldmethod=manual
set foldenable


" Search Settings
set hlsearch
set incsearch
set ignorecase
set smartcase


" Behaviour Settings
set wrap
set lazyredraw
set nu
set rnu
set showmatch
set vb
set wildmenu
set autoread
set encoding=utf-8
set clipboard=unnamed
set tw=79


" Appearance Settings
" colorscheme material
" let g:material_theme_style = 'default'
set colorcolumn=80
highlight colorcolumn ctermbg=7
highlight Folded ctermbg=None
set fillchars=""
let NERDTreeMinimalUI = 1
let NERDTreeDirArrows = 1


" Plugins
call plug#begin()
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdTree'    " File Explorer
Plug 'Shougo/deoplete.nvim', { 'do': ':UpdateRemotePlugins' }    " Completer
Plug 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'    " Fuzzy file finder
Plug 'jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs'    " NT tabs
Plug 'bling/vim-airline'    " Powerline
Plug 'Raimondi/delimitMate'    " Matchpairer
call plug#end()


" Plugin Settings
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
" delimitMate
let delimitMate_expand_cr = 1
augroup mydelimitMate
  au!
  au FileType markdown let b:delimitMate_nesting_quotes = ["`"]
  au FileType tex let b:delimitMate_quotes = ""
  au FileType tex let b:delimitMate_matchpairs = "(:),[:],{:},`:'"
  au FileType python let b:delimitMate_nesting_quotes = ['"', "'"]
augroup END
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> my entire sysinit.vim

I guess you mean init.vim

> set fillchars=“” does not work

It should not work. The proper syntax for `set` must be like this:

```
set fillchars=fold:\
```

Note that the previous command ends in a space.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer. I'm not sure why it worked for me in my original .vimrc file when I was using Vim, but hey - this works, and I understand the syntax enough to learn from this and apply it if something like this happens again. Cheers mate!